# Proper indexing in omnet++

Tags: network-programming, omnet++

In omnet++, would an indexing in the omnetpp.ini file like this be ok:

```
*.Member[0].numTcpApps = 2
*.Member[1..numberOfMembers].numTcpApps = 1
```

the parameter `numberOfMembers` has been specified in the .ned file as a usual integer variable. It is initialized to some value, e.g. 10.

What happens, if my `numberOfMembers` variable is set to only 1. In this case I should only have one Member (`Member[0]`). What happens to the second entry of the .ini file then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot use the value of a NED parameter in `omnetpp.ini`. However, you may achieve your goal using [wildcard patterns](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:wildcards) in `omnetpp.ini`.

Let's assume that a network is defined in `.ned` as:

```
network ExampleNetwork
{
    parameters:
        int numberOfMembers;
    submodules:
        Member[numberOfMembers] : SomeMemberType;
    // ...
}
```

Then in `omnetpp.ini` one can control the network. For example, to set `numTcpApps = 2` for `Member[0]` only, and `numTcpApps = 1` for all other submodules one should write:

```
*.numberOfMembers = 10
*.Member[0].numTcpApps = 2
*.Member[*].numTcpApps = 1   # i.e. Member[1], Member[2], ..., Member[9]
```

Take care of the order of entries in `omnetpp.ini`, because:

> The order of entries is very important with wildcards. When a key matches several wildcard patterns, the *first* matching occurrence is used.

As a consequence, the following order of entries:

```
*.numberOfMembers = 10
*.Member[*].numTcpApps = 1   # i.e. Member[0], Member[1], Member[2], ..., Member[9]
*.Member[0].numTcpApps = 2
```

will set `numTcpApps = 1` for all submodules. The last line is not taken into account because `Member[0]` has been already set by the entry `Member[*]`.

Comment: thx very much Jerzy D. !! I didn't know the order matters so much with wildcards. So you say one cannot use a value of a NED parameter in the .ini, but using `*.numberOfMembers` in the .ini can set this NED parameter in the .ned ?

Comment: Yes. The `omnetpp.ini` file is the place where one should (or even has to) set a value to every parameter defined in NED, for example `*.numberOfMembers = 10`. However, one cannot use a *value* of other parameter to set a parameter in `omnetpp.ini`, so we cannot write: `*.otherNedParameter = numberOfMembers`.